# How to use TortoiseGit to clone a Subversion repository with non-standard layout

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, tortoisegit

I use TortoiseGit a lot. I work with a client who keeps their code in SVN. Mostly, this works fine - I use the SVN facilities in TortoiseGit to check out their repos, work in Git, and use SVN dcommit to commit my code.

However I have just found a repo where my client has created a branch called `live`, but placed the branch at the root, rather than in `branches`. So the layout is:

```
/trunk
/live
/branches
/tags
```

I would like to checkout their `live` branch as a branch in git, so i can work on that branch, merge changes to/from trunk, and commit the results to the SVN repo.

Is there any way I can do that? I assume I will have to edit the `.git/config` file, but I'm not sure what I should put in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you first do a `git svn init ...`, then

change

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = ...
        fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
        branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
```

to

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = ...
        fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
        branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        branches = {live}:refs/remotes/origin/*
        tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
```

and then do `git svn fetch` you end up with the intended result.